# Getting a HTML h1 value to Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

If I wanted the value of a title that is going to be assigned to a header(h3) to become a javascript variable to bring information out of the local storage on a specific entry, how would I do that?

Comment: Using javascript, to create a variable with HTML, you must assign a id to the h1, and then create the var ( h1title = document.getElementById('h1title_id').innerHTML;) and its done.

Comment: Could you please provide a code sample?

Comment: You don't need to assign an id. `document.querySelector("h3")` will return the first `<h3>` element in the page `document.querySelectorAll("h3")` will return all `h3` elements in the page. both functions takes a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors) to decide what to select.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It really depends on your use-case what would be the best way to do that, and if you provide a little more code, the community might be better positioned to help you. In general, you can access the content of the first h3 tag by using:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].innerHTML
```

or if your tag has an id so you can use the below one

```
document.getElementById('yourId').innerHTML
```

or, if you have access to jQuery: `$('h3').text()`

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve it like this. But be careful with index of the h3 element if you have multiple h3

```js
var name = document.getElementById('name').innerHTML

console.log(name)
```

```html
<h3 id="name">Country_Name</h3>
```

Comment: Could I use an id on the h3 tag to make sure it doesn't become mixed up with multiple headings?

Comment: @Jonathon Of course you can and you should to avoid any error

Answer (score 1):

I would use textContent instead of innerHTML as it would be better performance wise.

```
var name = document.getElementById("myID").textContent
```

or by tag:

```
var name = document.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].textContent
```

And if you want to see it in the console:

```
console.log(name)
```