# Get value of element by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am a newbie in Javascript and try myself to looking for the way to solve my problem. I hope you can help me to fix this problem.

I have, example: Welcome to my home
How can I get the value (Welcome to my home) of h1 element.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a HTML h1 value to Javascript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328522/getting-a-html-h1-value-to-javascript-variable)

Comment: @Parco Oh thank u!

Answer (score 1):

add id to your h1 element
and add this Code in JS file `document.getElementById("the id you add in h1").textContent`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `querySelector`, like so:

```js
function myFunc(){
var x = document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML;
alert(x);
}

myFunc();
```

```html
<h1>Welcome to my Home</h1>
```

Comment: In my case, I have a lot of box like product package, in every single box have a <h1> like title name of product, I put all them one class. I have a button to click buy, so do u know how to when I click to the button I can get exactly name of product. Thank u

Comment: @duong-manh-dung does each of the product div class have a buy button? Also, are  you able to use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

in jquery you can use `h1:contains` without having to add any id, for example :

```js
$( "h1:contains('Welcome to my home')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Welcome to my home</h1>
```